# Forward specific external traffic to LAN server

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, port-forwarding

I want to redirect the incoming traffic to my server, in which iptables is working, to another server in LAN. However, I only want this to work if the incoming traffic is coming from a specific external IP address. Otherwise, the traffic should be dropped.

Let me put an example to clarify it:

- External client IP: 88.88.88.88
- Server IP (in same LAN): 172.26.0.99
- Destination IP (in same LAN): 172.26.0.11

**Redirection example**

1. Client (88.88.88.88) connects to `SERVER IP (172.26.0.99)`
2. Traffic is tunnelled to `Destination IP (172.26.0.11)`.

**Drop example**

1. Stranger client (66.66.66.66) tries to connect to `SERVER IP (172.26.0.99)`
2. Traffic is `DROPPED`

Comment: Is *server* the gateway of *destination* ? If no, does *destination* need to keep seeing 88.88.88.88 as source?

Comment: It’s not the gateway, as the gateway would be the ISP router. Destination doesn’t need to keep seeing the 88.88.88.88 source, it just need to be reached through the tunnel I described.

Comment: is there a reason why we speak about lan and hides the ips? 10/8 172.16/16 and 192.168/16 is not routed to the internet

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was easier to read that way. I will update the question using my real LAN IPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to forward *all* traffic from 88.88.88.88 to the protected server 172.26.0.11. Here's an example using NAT:

```sh
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i <wan-if> -s 88.88.88.88 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.26.0.11
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 88.88.88.88 -d 172.26.0.11 -j SNAT --to-source 172.26.0.99
iptables -A FORWARD -s 88.88.88.88 -d 172.26.0.11 -j ACCEPT
```

Alternatively, forwarding on a per port basis, use `ipvs` or SystemD sockets or `iptables -j REDIRECT` to set up the forwarding and firewall the port. Example with ipvs and iptables:

```sh
sysctl net.ipv4.vs.conntrack=1

ipvsadm -A -t "172.26.0.99:<port>" -s rr
ipvsadm -a -t "172.26.0.99:<port>" -r "172.26.0.11:<port>" -m

iptables -A INPUT -s 88.88.88.88 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow 88.88.88.88"
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -m comment --comment "Catch-all drop"
```

Comment: I was thinking about writing my own reply, but decided against it. Add a SNAT to the POSTROUTING chain and your example will work: ```iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 88.88.88.88 -d 172.26.0.11 -j SNAT --to-source 172.26.0.99``` otherwise, the reply from the "protected" server will take a different route than the initial packet took! And, do not forget to turn on ```ip_forwarding```...