# How can I redirect range of ports from server to another lan device using IPTABLES

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding, redirection

I have a server and few lan devices that are hosting custom services on custom ports.  All of the devices use linux. Only the server is exposed to the internet (ports are forwarded).

I'm trying to redirect all traffic on x ports range to device 1 range of ports for example:

server_ip: 192.168.5.5

device 1 ip: 10.0.0.1

A request on 192.168.5.5:4001 should be redirected to device 1 (10.0.0.1) on port 2001

I'm trying to redirect any traffic on the port range 4001:4050 to device1 on ports 2001:2050 and external ports should match internal ports (4001 -> 2001, 4002 -> 2002 ..etc)

I used the following IPTable rules and it worked fine for single ports redirection but for the port range it does not match: (4001 sometimes connects to 2005 where it should connect to 2001)

IPTABLE rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4000:4050 -j DNAT --to-destination Device_1_IP:2000-2050

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d device1_ip -p tcp --dport 2000:2050 -j SNAT --to-source Server public ip
```

I've also tried using rinetd but couldnt figure out how to redirect a whole port range.

kind regards

Comment: Can you try this ? it worked for me. https://serverfault.com/questions/1080060/forward-specific-external-traffic-to-lan-server/1103824#1103824

Comment: @Dwija I've tried that but the issue is IPTABLES does not match the ports (1 to 1)